# Почему не работает псевдоселектор first-child?

Tags: html, css

Есть базовая `HTML` структура с двумя параграфами в `Body`.
Почему, когда я пробовал обратиться к первому параграфу через псевдо селектор `p:first-child`, ничего не вышло, но сработало `p:nth-child(2)`. Ведь это первый параграф в родителе `Body`, почему так?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <style> 
 p:nth-child(2) {
 color:red; 
 }  
  </style>
 </head>
 
 <body>
  <p>Paragraph-1</p>
  <p>Paragraph-2</p>
 </body> 
 
</html>
```

Comment: Ну не знаю http://codepen.io/bustexz/pen/pyrBpe. Все работает. Да и вообще плохо обращаться к глобальному `p`, они уже могут быть на странице, и им присваивается твой стиль. Добавь класс к своему `p.someClass:first-child { ... }` и проверь

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/post/119139/, отсчет идет с header

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев Да, я просто изучал псевдоклассы и столкнулся с этой проблемой. В случае с p.someClass:first-child я обращаюсь ко всем параграфам с этим классом и первым у своих родителей, верно?

То есть если у меня несколько дивов, в них много параграфов, в том числе парочка с этим классом, этот селектор выберет каждый первый параграф с этим классом в каждом диве (не просто первый в диве<, а первый с этим классом) - верно?

Comment: @soledar10 Очень интересно... но в head у меня нет p, разве что в css коде в теге style - и он считается?
P.S. Заметил только что что по ошибке использовал Header вместо Head, сейчас перепроверю с Head.

Comment: @MaximVelichkin будет считаться самый первый p.someClass который есть на странице, где бы он не был. Не имеет разницы вложен он в див или нет. Если сделать `div p.someClass:first-child` , то будет выбираться первый `p.someClass` в каждом диве.

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев Понял, спасибо! Я заменил header на head и у меня в редакторе все заработало с first-child, но в онлайн-сервисах по-прежнему не работает: https://jsfiddle.net/bzkgpge0/#&togetherjs=cgjGAeCtFr Я догадываюсь что причина в том что CSS встроен в HTML, но хочется разобраться, почему это происходит...

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев Если разбить код на CSS отдельно HTML отдельно - все работает - https://jsfiddle.net/bzkgpge0/# У меня в редакторе работает и если CSS встроен в HTML. Почему в онлайн-сервисах интерпретируется неправильно?...

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/by7jh5wd/ работает, просто тебе не надо вставлять там теги `html, body, head`. Они уже есть, и ты ломаешь этим структуру страницы

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев Вот оно что, спасибо большое!

Comment: @soledar10 Спасибо большое за ссылку, не заметил ошибку в теге.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

обернул твой код в `<div>` и все заработало

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <style> 
 p:first-child{
 color:red; 
 }  
  </style>
 </head>
 
 <body>
  <div>
    <p>Paragraph-1</p>
  <p>Paragraph-2</p>
    </div>
 </body> 
 
</html>
```

Comment: Интересно! То есть first-child в моем примере работает в оффлайн редакторе, потому что там вся HTML структура создается с нуля, не работает в онлайн-сервисах, потому что дополнительные head, body, style нарушают втроенную в сервис структуру, но если нужно обязательно ее сохранить, можно использовать такой вариант, здорово! Только не понимаю, почему это работает)

Comment: Ведь в этом случае все равно добавляются "лишние" для онлайн-сервиса теги.

Answer (score 3):

Это не работает в конкретном сниппете, потому что если посмотреть сгенерированную разметку можно увидеть, что тег `<style>` был перенесен в `body` и первый из `p` стал действительно вторым элементом внутри `body`.

```js
console.log(document.body.innerHTML);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    p:nth-child(2) {
      color: red;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <p>Paragraph-1</p>
  <p>Paragraph-2</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Чтобы поправить, вместо этого можно использовать [`first-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-of-type), либо обернуть нужные элементы в какой-нибудь контейнер как в соседнем ответе.

Либо, как уже указали в комментарии, не вставлять теги html, head, body в разметку, так как они все равно генерируются автоматически, а повторные просто убираются. И использовать для скриптов, разметки и css специальные поля в сниппетах.

```js
console.log(document.body.innerHTML);
```

```css
p:first-child {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p>Paragraph-1</p>
<p>Paragraph-2</p>
```