# Помогите составить селектор похитрее

Tags: css, css-selectors

1. Селекторы должны перечисляться у одного правила `{color: red}`.
2. Отменять значения нельзя - не известно какие они были до замены вашим селектором.

Надо чтобы было так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код такой:

```css
.parrent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.child {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parrent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
<div class="separator"></div>
<div class="parrent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

ps: `.parrent ~ .parrent .child:nth-child(3)` - очевидно, можно не писать...

Comment: А эти элементы будут также повторяться каждые 6 раз?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov Нет. Тут каждая строчка отдельный родительский блок, в котором по 3 элемента. "Инверсии" выбора тут тоже нет, это случайно.

Comment: почему `.parrent ~ .parrent .child:nth-child(3)` _очевидно_ можно не писать? Какое в итоге должно быть состояние? Нужно изменить только один элемент?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.parrent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.child {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid;
  background-color: blue;
}

.parrent:nth-child(4n+1) > .child:nth-child(1),
.parrent:nth-child(4n+1) > .child:nth-child(2),
.parrent:nth-child(4n+3) > .child:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parrent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
<div class="separator"></div>
<div class="parrent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
<div class="separator"></div>
<div class="parrent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
<div class="separator"></div>
<div class="parrent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: `.parrent:nth-child(4n+1) > .child:nth-child(1)` в модельном коде работает. В боевом - нет. Хрень какая-то. (

Comment: @AndreyFedorov Значит добавляются ещё элементы, может с помощью JS.

Comment: в боевом коде не работает псевдоселектор для родительского элемента. Почему - пока идей нет.

Comment: в общем тут какая проблема с подсчетом номера элемента, наткнулся на такой вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/508467/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BF%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80-first-child

Comment: @AndreyFedorov Это очевидно, что проблема с подчётом элемента, не знаю чем помочь.

Comment: чем помочь, чем помочь... подогнал в боевом коде методом тыка :(          `.parrent:nth-child(3n+1) > .child:not(:nth-child(3)),
.parrent:nth-child(3n+2) > .child:nth-child(3)
`